# ASP.NET Multi tenant application with tenant specific roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

We have a multi-tenant ASP.NET application.  So far tenants have been isolated from each other, however now we have Agencies that manage multiple tenants and want to be able to manage all their tenants with a single user account.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish that, hopefully without much change to the existing technologies that we are using.

Relevant technical details:

- AspNetSqlMembershipProvider for both membership and roles
- C# 4.0 (soon to be 4.5)
- Forms Authentication
- Both aspx and MVC (v3) pages
- Assume 100 or more tenants, so any solution needs to support that

I believe the requirements are very similar to the security model for SQL Server.  We have one set of logins which represent all the users that can login to the system.  Users should be able to be given roles to one or more databases (tenants).  Example: User Bob has admin role in company A, but only user role in company B.  We also have a "sysadmin" role for my company's employees which allow us access to any tenant as well as specialized administrative privileges such as create/delete tenants, etc.

I've done a lot of research into various libraries, frameworks, etc, and I haven't found any convincing evidence that some other library or framework will be better than what we currently have.  So I'm currently thinking of just figuring out how to make Sql Membership provider do what I want, unless someone can point me in a better direction.  I'm also not sure I know the best terms to search for in this.

I've got 2 options I'm considering:

1. Add only a handful of roles to the membership provider and handle all the questions of "does the current user have this role in this tenant" outside of membership provider.  Membership provider would be used to handle basic access to the system.
2. Add tenant specific roles to membership provider.  We would have (# of roles) x (# of tenants) total roles in the system.  Each new tenant would add another set of roles to the system, e.g. "Tenant A:Admin", "Tenant A:User", etc.  Would need some additional tables to manage the relations as well as probably some custom code to ensure that access is requesting the correct tenant-specific role from the membership provider.

Are either of these options good? Or should I be looking elsewhere for support for this?

Comment: Hi Ted, I recently answered a similar question here, maybe it is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21165928/304832 In short, I think option #1 is going to be the best option.

Comment: Sounds like handling the tenant specific roles outside of Membership provider and just let membership provider do coarse grained access is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to shoehorn multitenancy into any out of the box role provider, so you might as well keep using SqlMembershipProvider (and SqlRoleProvider). Even the newest Microsoft.AspNet.Identity still assumes a vanilla many-to-many between users and roles. What you really need is to add a 3rd column to the primary key of that many-to-many table, which will id your tenant, i.e.:

```
user: 6
role: 4
tenant: 17

user: 6
role: 9
tenant: 18 (and so on)
```

...with this, you are able to have users with different privileges for different tenancies, all using the same set of role names.

If you went with option #2, then your [Authorize] attributes would explode. Imagine this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "TenantA:Admin", "TenantB:Admin", ...)]
public ActionResult Post(int id, SomeViewModel model) {}
```

... all of those attributes would have to be written at compile time unless you went with a custom AuthorizeAttribute, which you could do. But even then you are left creating a new set of roles each time you add a tenant to the system, which should not be necessary.

Comment: I'm using your 1st approach, and add one more property 'companyId' in my `ApplicationUserRole`  , but I'm stucked in override the AddToRole or IsInRole these functions. these function doesn't accept companyId. I'm trying to override these functions to get companyId in picture. I've post my question [here]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071800/how-to-overload-usermanager-addtoroleasyncstring-userid-string-role). If you could help, that will be great! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I work on a big multi-tenancy application. We came to the conclusion that it was easier to maintain separate databases per tenant, and have the web application automatically switch database contexts, rather than try and use an over-complicated database schema to model different tenants.

**The benefits**

1. Tenant data is compartmentalized by default into different databases
2. Tenant data can be exported as a database dump for client MI
3. Database design is vastly simplified

**The drawbacks**

1. You have to manage multiple databases - operations challenge
2. You have to develop database switching code

**Implementation using multiple databases**

1. We used a configuration database that has client settings based on an account code. That account code can come from a login screen or you can map subdomain to client code.
2. When the app starts you load all tenants into cache (containing connection strings)
3. On every request you have to determine the client and then switch the db context

I have also developed a multi-tenant application that uses a single database. You quite quickly have problems making sure that you don't cross tenant data. Every query needs to include a tenant id filter. The database queries are therefore always slower as a result, although you can index everything you can to try and improve the situation.

With regards to the Membership question, you can install the membership schema into each tenant database.

**What doesn't work**

The ideal alternative would be to [dynamically switch the ApplicationName](http://cgeers.com/2009/10/24/asp-net-supporting-dynamic-applications/), but although it seems to work, [ApplicationName is not thread safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.applicationname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), therefore this would not be reliable:

> Because a single default membership provider instance is used for all
>   of the requests served by an HttpApplication object, you can have
>   multiple requests executing concurrently and attempting to set the
>   ApplicationName property value. The ApplicationName property is not
>   thread safe for multiple writes, and changing the ApplicationName
>   property value can result in unexpected behavior for multiple users of
>   an application. We recommend that you avoid writing code that allows
>   users to set the ApplicationName property, unless you must. An example
>   of an application where setting the ApplicationName property may be
>   required is an administrative application that manages membership data
>   for multiple applications. Such an application should be a single-user
>   application and not a Web application.

**Alternative: MembershipReboot**

Multi-tenancy is hard in .Net. An open source alternative to using the built in Membership is to use [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/), written by [Brock Allen](http://brockallen.com/about/). It has some excellent features including multi-tenant support out-of-the-box:

> 1. single- or multi-tenant account management
> 2. flexible account storage design (relational/SQL or object/NoSql), samples using both EF and RavenDB
> 3. claims-aware user identities
> 4. support for account registration, email verification, password reset, etc.
> 5. account lockout for multiple failed login attempts (password guessing)
> 6. extensible templating for email notifications
> 7. customizable username, password and email validation
> 8. notification system for account activity and updates (e.g. for auditing)
> 9. account linking with external identity providers (enterprise or social)
> 10. supports certificate based authentication
> 11. proper password storage (via PBKDF2)
> 12. configurable iterations
> 13. defaults to OWASP recommendations for iterations (e.g. 64K in year 2012)
> 14. two factor authentication support via mobile phone SMS messages or client certificates
>
> The most common use case will be to integrate this into an ASP.NET or
>   ASP.NET MVC application, though the library can also be used over a
>   network as a service.

**Alternative: ServiceStack REST**

Another alternative if you are building modern web applications that heavily use JavaScript MVC frameworks such as AngularJS, EmberJS or BackboneJS is to use ServiceStack REST services. ServiceStack has a [long list of Authentication features](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization), and from my experience of SS, I find it has an extremely well thought out API model.

[image: ServiceStack Authentication]

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the OP's User Bob would have to create 2 user accounts, one for company A and another for company B?

Comment: Correct. But why would a user A from company A be accessing information in company B?

Comment: It looks like a requirement in the OP: "we have Agencies that manage multiple tenants and want to be able to manage all their tenants with a single user account" Don't get me wrong, I think this is a good solution in some multitenant situations.

Comment: We have separate db per tenant with a configuration database.  The membership data is in the configuration database.

Comment: @TedElliott We also use a single config database, but that just determines the tenant db connection string. How do you compartmentalize the tenant users in they are held in the config db?