# How to add user to role using UserId and RoleId of Asp.net core identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Like ,

usermanager.AddUserToRole(userrole.UserId, userrole.RoleId);

I am stucked here, Can anyone please help to add user to specific Role of a specific Company (Multi tenancy)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple demo about how to add role to user:

1.Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    public HomeController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task CreateRolesandUsers()
    {

        bool x = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
        if (!x)
        {
            // first we create Admin role   
            var role = new IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Admin";
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);                                            
        }
        //Then we create a user 
        var user = new IdentityUser();
        user.UserName = "default";
        user.Email = "default@default.com";
        string userPWD = "122@Xsdf";

        IdentityResult chkUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userPWD);

        //Add default User to Role Admin    
        if (chkUser.Succeeded)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
        }
    }
}
```

2.Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
//services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the solution is adding a tenant table map with the role table (n-n). When clients query userInfo, check tenant before map userInfo with roles

Comment: Hi, I have added mapping of tenant and role table but while adding User of Tenant1 to Role (Administrator) of Tenant1, its not letting me add using userManager.AddToRoleAsync as it takes User and role name parameter. In my project there are multiple admin role in AspNetRoles Table i.e. 1 tenant, 1 admin role so i will need roleId to add User to Particular Tenant's Admin role. So how to achieve this?

Comment: Hum... I unknow your problem with this solution. If your project has multiple admin roles, the primary key is role_name  + tenantId -> It solves your problem

Comment: Ok then how to use/modify AddToRoleAsync(TUser, String roleName)  method of UserManager to add users role mapping info into aspNetUserRoles table

Comment: You must modify AspNetRoles table constrains Name unique. The solution to modify AddToRoleAsync method in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071800/how-to-overload-usermanager-addtoroleasyncstring-userid-string-role

Comment: Hi Jun, Thanks for the quick help. I will go through the solution and lets see if it works with my solution. And sure will give u reputation :)