# The property is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

After adding encryption I can't seem to add user roles. Since I get the following Error:

> The instance of entity type 'UserRole' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Username', 'Rolename'} is already being tracked.

However, I'm not sure where I am tracking the record as I am only now creating it. And why is it only now that I am changing the values that the issue comes up? And I have no foreign key constraints on these tables. Not yet anyway.

### Calling Code:

```
async void AddUser()
{
    var userAdded = await UserService.AddUser(User, Role, Password);
    if (userAdded)
    {
        await UserService.AddUserRole(User, Role);
        UserRoles.Add(new UserRole() { Username = User, Rolename = Role });
    }

    User = string.Empty;
    Password = string.Empty;

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

### AddUser Code:

```
public async Task<bool> AddUser(string username, string role, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(role) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        return false;

    var usernameEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(username); // 4gXmaWCArsBPjeJfIyX5qg==
    var user = await UserRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == usernameEncrypt);

    if (user == null)
    {
        var passwordEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(password); // 4gXmaWCArsBPjeJfIyX5qg==
        await UserRepository.CreateAsync(new Users() { Password = passwordEncrypt, Username = usernameEncrypt });
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Add User Role:

```
public async Task<bool> AddUserRole(string username, string role)
{
    var userrole = await UserRolesrepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username && x.Rolename == role);

    if (userrole == null)
    {
        var userEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(username); // 3qsWsTYQYtIDKxk5rLCb5w==
        var roleEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(role); // PmWB4sczzBA5jGY2MePNdg==
        await UserRolesrepository.CreateAsync(new UserRole() { Username = userEncrypt, Rolename = roleEncrypt }); // <--- ERROR
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Additional Info

Below I have the Fluent API Code

```
/* UserRoles */
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Username, e.Rolename });
});
```

Comment: Hi @user15119845,Not sure what is your `UserRolesrepository.CreateAsync`. Here is a simple demo about how to add role to user, you could follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59623647/11398810.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I of course can't test this, but from looking at the code this is my best guess.

When you are checking for an existing user you are using the encrypted version of the username to check if it exists already:

```
var usernameEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(username); // 4gXmaWCArsBPjeJfIyX5qg==
var user = await UserRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == usernameEncrypt);
```

However when you are checking user roles you are doing the encryption after the check, so my guess is that it will **always** return `null,
and then you are saving the encrypted role:

```
var userrole = await UserRolesrepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username && x.Rolename == role);

if (userrole == null) //im guessing this is always true
{
    var userEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(username); // 3qsWsTYQYtIDKxk5rLCb5w==
    var roleEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(role); // PmWB4sczzBA5jGY2MePNdg==
    await UserRolesrepository.CreateAsync(new UserRole() { Username = userEncrypt, Rolename = roleEncrypt }); // <--- ERROR
}
```

I would move the encryption before the check just like you do for users:

```
var userEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(username); // 3qsWsTYQYtIDKxk5rLCb5w==
var roleEncrypt = MarelEncryption.EncryptString(role); // PmWB4sczzBA5jGY2MePNdg==
var userrole = await UserRolesrepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == userEncrypt && x.Rolename == roleEncrypt);

if (userrole == null)
{
    await UserRolesrepository.CreateAsync(new UserRole() { Username = userEncrypt, Rolename = roleEncrypt }); // <--- ERROR
}
```