# How can I customize AddToRoleAsync in Identity .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to add a field called ChartId to the UserRoles table.
After that, I want to save the ID chart for the user when I roll it. To do this, I use the method: AddToRoleAsync. How can I customize this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to add the ChartId property to the UserRoles table, you could create a Custom ApplicationRole class inherit from IdentityRole, then, add the custom properties, then update the DbContext to use the custom ApplicationRole and register the custom DbContext, code like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :
    IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

More detail information, please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-model).

Second, if you want to customize/override the AddToRoleAsync method, I think perhaps you have to create the custom UserManager and userRoleStore, you could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071800/how-to-overload-usermanager-addtoroleasyncstring-userid-string-role).

Besides, since the ChartId is on the Roles table, when add a new role, you could set the ChartId property. Then, when you add a user to the Role using AddToRoleAsync method, there is no need to set ChartId property. If you want to update the Role's ChartId value, you could find the Role first and update it, and then add the User to the Role using AddToRoleAsync method. In this scenario, I think there is no need to customize the AddToRoleAsync method, we could only create a custom ApplicationRole class.